# How to linearly interpolate animation curve in unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After researching for hours and hours I am just not able to linearly interpolate two animation curve,I need something like Mathf.lerp for animation curve,I had try with inTangent and OutTangent with keyframes of the animation curve but it does not store the values,am I missing something ? 
Need guidance,this would help me a lot in my project,thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your use case, what are those two animation curves and what are you trying to achieve? I use `AnimationCurve` to define curves which I interpolate for various purposes using [`AnimationCurve.Evaluate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html), but your question needs clarification.

Comment: Sure ,i can explain to you in the most simplest way ,just like how we use  Mathf.lerp(float a, float b,float time) ,I need something like AnimationCurve.Lerp(animationCurve a,animation curve b,float time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are looking to "*morph*" one animation curve into another. This imho depends on your use case.

Assuming both curves are defined between [0.0, 1.0], I'd calculate the curve value for t in both, and interpolate linearly both results over the same time.

```cs
/*
* Evaluates two AnimationCurve objects, and interpolates linearly
* between the results, effectively "morphing" from curve A to curve
* B in a linear fashion.
* Both curves must be defined between 0.0 and 1.0, and t must be
* within the same 0.0-1.0 range too.
*/
public float EvaluateLerpTwoCurves(AnimationCurve a, AnimationCurve b, float t) {
    float valueA = a.Evaluate (t);
    float valueB = b.Evaluate (t);
    float result = Mathf.Lerp(valueA, valueB, t);
    return result;
}
```

You may wish to interpolate between both `AnimationCurve` using a different approach (not linearly like `Mathf.Lerp` does), you could even use a third AnimationCurve to define how to *morph* between both curves.

Note that the suggested code above requires both curves to be defined between 0.0 and 1.0, and t must be within the same 0.0-1.0 range too.